# Laptop hangs when lid is closed

Tags: lenovo, freeze, 19.10, lid

I currently have Ubuntu 19.10 installed on my Lenovo T440s. 
When I close my laptop's lid and re-open it later in an hour or so later, 4 out 5 times, the laptop will just freeze. Keyboard doens't respond, touchpad doesn't work. Nothing responds but I can see what is on my screen. The only way is to force restart the laptop.

I have set my logind.conf to hibernate and suspend and they both still freeze.

How can I fix this?